# ¿Cómo devolver datos que tengan registros en ambas tablas sql server?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedure, union

Tengo una consulta y es la siguiente:

Tengo una tabla **A** y una tabla **B** ambos son consultados por rango fechas y unidos por un `UNION`.

Lo que deseo es que devuelva datos siempre y cuando ambas tablas tengan datos.

Cual seria la forma correcta de hacer ese funcionalidad.

```
CREATE PROC spConsultarxFechas
@fechaDesde date,
@fechaHasta date
AS
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM A
WHERE A.fechaCreacionA>=@fechaDesde AND A.fechaCreacionA<=@fechaHasta
UNION
SELECT * FROM B
WHERE B.fechaCreacionB>=@fechaDesde AND B.fechaCreacionB<=@fechaHasta
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una posible solución es invalidar una consulta si la otra no recupera filas:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM A
    WHERE A.fechaCreacionA >= @fechaDesde 
        AND A.fechaCreacionA <= @fechaHasta
        AND EXIST(SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM B
                    WHERE fechaCreacionB >= @fechaDesde 
                    AND fechaCreacionB <= @fechaHasta)
UNION
SELECT * 
    FROM B
    WHERE B.fechaCreacionB >= @fechaDesde 
        AND B.fechaCreacionB <= @fechaHasta
        AND EXIST(SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM A
                    WHERE fechaCreacionA >= @fechaDesde 
                    AND fechaCreacionA <= @fechaHasta)
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear 2 variable que controlen el número de registros (`@CuantosA` y `@CuantosB`) y por comparación, si ambas son mayores de cero, con un `IF`, realizas la consulta.

```
CREATE PROC spConsultarxFechas
@fechaDesde date,
@fechaHasta date
AS
BEGIN
 DECLARE @CuantosA int = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM A
 WHERE A.fechaCreacionA>=@fechaDesde AND A.fechaCreacionA<=@fechaHasta)
 DECLARE @CuantosB int = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM B
 WHERE A.fechaCreacionB>=@fechaDesde AND B.fechaCreacionA<=@fechaHasta)

 IF (@CuantosA >0 and @CuantosB>0)
 BEGIN
   SELECT * FROM A
   WHERE A.fechaCreacionA>=@fechaDesde AND A.fechaCreacionA<=@fechaHasta
   UNION
   SELECT * FROM B
   WHERE B.fechaCreacionB>=@fechaDesde AND B.fechaCreacionB<=@fechaHasta
 END
END
```